# Where to put javascript code when you should use variable from controller in Rails applications?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Normally, we put javascript files to app/assets/javascripts folder.
But what if we need use controller instance_val, should we still put this javascript file to the folder we mentioned before, or put javascript code in the views file as a snippet?

I try to add a slider to a view. I'm using jQueryUI.
Here is my code:

```
$ ->
$("#slider").slider(
 range: true,
 min: 0,
 max: <%= @t.amount %>,
 values: [0, <%= @t.amount / 2 %>],
 slide: (event, ui)->
     $("#range_from").val(ui.values[0])
     $("#range_to").val(ui.values[1])
 )
```

I try to use @t in the js file, but I got a Nil Class error.
I don't want to put this code in the view file directly for a good file organise.
Is there a better way to implement this code ?

Comment: Can you show us what you are trying to do?  An example perhaps so that it's clear.  You should not expose your controller instance variables, really, anywhere.  You should pass them as locals to views.  But since you talk about `app/assets/javascripts` an example code snippet would definitely be better.

Comment: Check this out http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast. We have been using https://github.com/gazay/gon Gem in http://hireinfluence.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do either each

1. putting it at the bottom of the view "Which i don't recommend" as:

   ```
   :javascript
     $("#slider").slider(
     range: true,
     min: 0,
     max: <%= @t.amount %>,
     values: [0, <%= @t.amount / 2 %>],
     slide: (event, ui)->
        $("#range_from").val(ui.values[0])
        $("#range_to").val(ui.values[1])
     )
   ```
2. Or by adding data target attribute and calling it from your assets as follows:

   in Your View add the data-target

   ```
   <div class="info" data-target="<%= @t %>"></div>
   ```

   Then in your assets call the variable

   ```
     t = $(".info").attr("data-target")
     $("#slider").slider(
     range: true,
     min: 0,
     max: t,
     values: [0, t/2],
     slide: (event, ui)->
        $("#range_from").val(ui.values[0])
        $("#range_to").val(ui.values[1])
     )
   ```